Unity C# Pendulum withRotation
I am a unity newbie, can I get some help?
So basically I created a pendulum, but i added some function where, if it reached the maximum height possible, the Y axis of the pendulum will rotate by 180 degrees but the Y axis wasn't rotating.
Here's the code:
using UnityEngine;

public class PendulumScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float limit = 75f;
    public bool randomStart = false;
    private float random = 0;
    private bool limitReached = false;
    private Quaternion originalRotation;

    void Awake()
    {
        if (randomStart)
        {
            random = Random.Range(0f, 1f);
        }

        // Save the original rotation
        originalRotation = transform.localRotation;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        float angle = limit * Mathf.Sin(Time.time + random * speed);
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

        if (!limitReached && (angle == limit))
        {
            // Rotate around the Y-axis by 180 degrees
            transform.Rotate(0, 180 * Time.time, 0);
            limitReached = true;
            limit *= -1; // turns limit into negative
        }
        else if (limitReached && (angle == -limit))
        {
            // Reset to original rotation which is Y = 0
            transform.localRotation = originalRotation;
            limitReached = false;
            limit *= -1; // turns limit into positive
        }
    }
}


i was trying the rotation using if !limitreached and else if limitreached and it does rotate but flickering since its doing the rotation all the time, thats why I added another condition, but it appears the best condition that i could think of is not working, im hoping to figure out on whats wrong with the (angle == limit) condition that it's not being satisfied or maybe what really is the reason why its not working.

in my maths, rotating an "axis" (i.e., a line) by 180° will give the exact same line, if the rotation center is on the line. Could you clarify?

using a Unity 3D, im creating an amusement park ride called "VIkings" which moves like a pendulum, and im adding a feature which it rotates to 180 degrees if it reached the maximum height possible.

still don't really get it but I will try - you have an pendulum object that rotates around a different axis (x or z), right? And now every time it passes the top most point you it to additionally perform a rotation of the cabin around Y?

But how is this supposed to happen if you also overwrite every frame with transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle); .. further never compare float using == .. due to precision this might never become true ... and then further your condition is only true for a single frame ... your rotation should probably rather happen during various frames ...

yes it will rotate the Y axis  every time it passes the top most point, the transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle); is the pendulum movement which only moves by Z axis

i see, ill try changing the conditions involving float

update: so the thing is, the condition is now being satisfied, but the problem now is after the condition got satisfied, it rotates for like 0.5s while flickering and teleporting to the other side

So if I got that right what you want is actually two rotations

The pendulum rotates continuously forth and back on the Z axis
Additionally once reaching the limit on either side you additionally want the 180° rotation on Y

There are various issues with your approach

This
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, angle);

Does NOT only rotate on the Z axis! It rather hard resets y = 0.

Never compare float using ==!
Due to precision limits this might never ever be true

Your condition is also only true during max one single frame.
You rather want to trigger a continuous rotation around Y

I also think that
Time.time + random * speed

is not quite what you wanted to use but rather e.g.
(Time.time + random) * speed


And
transform.Rotate(0, 180 * Time.time, 0);

Does NOT rotate by 180° ... the more time has passed the more it will rotate here!


I would actually treat this as two individual rotations and handle them separately:
public class PendulumScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 1.5f;
    public float limit = 75f;
    public bool randomStart = false;
    public float yRotationSpeed = 45.0f; // degrees per second

    private float rotationZ;
    private float rotationY;
    private bool performingYFlip;
    private float time;
    private float targetYRotation;

    void Awake()
    {
        // instead of selecting a random sin value
        // I would rather select a random start time
        // This way you have a clear check when enough time has passed to 
        // perform the flip
        if(randomStart)
        {
            // sinus range is in radians => full cycle every 2π
            time = Random.Range(0f, 2 * Mathf.PI) * speed;

            // if required could also adjust the initial targetYRotation based on the random time here
        }
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // simply increase the timer by the time passed since last frame
        time += Time.deltaTime * speed;

        // calculate Z rotation as before
        rotationZ = Mathf.Sin(time) * limit;

        // Use approximate equality for angles
        // note that due to the sinus even this might never be true within a frame
        //if(Mathf.Approximately(rotationZ, limit))
        // so you might even use a wider range like e.g.
        if(!performingYFlip  && Mathf.Abs(rotationZ - limit) <= /*Some Threshold in angles*/ 5f)
        {
            // initiate a flip
            performingYFlip = true;
            targetYRotation += 180f;
        }

        if(performingYFlip)
        {
            // continuous Y rotation as long as performingYFlip remains true
            yRotation = Mathf.MoveTowards(yRotation, targetYRotation, yRotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

            if(Mathf.Approximately(yRotation, targetYRotation))
            {
                performingYFlip = false;
            }
        }

        // and finally apply both rotations together
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, yRotation, zRotation);
    }
}


thank you so much sir, your teaching enlightened me in many ways.
